# Access a class modules variables within a second class

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there's a way in which I can share variables between instances of separate class modules?

I have two classes:

- `Class 1`
- `Class 2`

Inside class 1, I have multiple global variables which I would like `Class 2` to have access to once instantiated.

I *could* use get and set properties for each of the variables but I have about 40/50 so it just seems a bit tedious.

So, instead, I'm trying to pass the current instance of `Class 1` to `Class 2` using set property.

I've created a minimal example to illustrate my current efforts:

**Class 1:**

```
Public test As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Call setTest

    Dim b As Class2
    Set b = New Class2
End Sub

Public Property Set Classed(ByRef vClass As Class1)
    Set vClass = Me
End Property

Public Sub setTest(t As String)
    test = "Sam"
End Sub
```

**Class 2:**

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Dim newClass As Class1

    newClass.Classed = newClass
    ' Want to be able to access the test String from class 1 

End Sub
```

Obviously what I am doing at the moment is incorrect, so am wondering if someone could point out where I'm going wrong and show me how to achieve this class sharing?

> Just to add: when running the code, I receive a compile error at line: `newClass.Classed = newClass`. Error: Invalid use of property

Comment: You could create a workbook global collection so both class variables are stored within it and accessible by both; you will need Set and Get procedures within both classes, or alternatively store pointers to each class so they can be referenced

Comment: @Flephal ah sounds like a good idea. But instead, could I form the get and set procedures inside the global module instead of having to repeat in both? Thanks for the response btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure but I sense a bit of a [Circular Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240808(v=vs.60).aspx) in your example?

> **What Are Circular References?** 
>   A circular reference occurs when two objects hold references to each other.

You could try an alternative by exposing a Dictionary object through your class, where the *Key* will be your "variable name", and the *Value* will hold the actual value.

An example could be:

---

**Class1**

```
Option Explicit

Private mList As Object

Public Property Get List() As Object
    Set List = mList
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mList = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

**Implementation:**

```
Sub ClassTest()
    Dim a As Class1
    Set a = New Class1

    Dim b As Class1
    Set b = New Class1

    a.List("VarName") = "Sam"  'Set
    b.List("VarName") = a.List("VarName") 'Get / Set

    Debug.Print b.List("VarName")   'Get

    Set a = Nothing
    Set b = Nothing
End Sub

'Output
'Sam
```

Comment: Ok the dictionary approach seems like it would be more efficient. But how would I go about giving a separate class access to this dictionary? In your example you created 2 instances of the same class.